# What am I allowed to put in a textPath tag so that it follows the curve?

Tags: html, css, tags, curve

I've copied the second to last HTML snippet form [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/svg/curved-text-along-path/) below and edited it by adding `<p>uffa</p>` in the text. As you can see, `uffa` is show at the bottom of the page instead of on the curve. Why is that? What am I allowed to put in the `textPath` tag so that it follows the curve?

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 500">
    <path id="curve" d="M73.2,148.6c4-6.1,65.5-96.8,178.6-95.6c111.3,1.2,170.8,90.3,175.1,97" />
    <text width="500">
      <textPath xlink:href="#curve">
        Dangerous Curves Ahead <p>uffa</p>
      </textPath>
    </text>
</svg>
```

Adding CSS tag in case there's a CSS trick to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`p`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p) is not an [SVG element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element) and therefore it is placed outside the SVG viewbox. Alternatively you can make use of [`tspan`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/tspan) which is used to define a subtext within `<text>`

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 500">
    <path id="curve" d="M73.2,148.6c4-6.1,65.5-96.8,178.6-95.6c111.3,1.2,170.8,90.3,175.1,97" />
    <text width="500">
      <textPath xlink:href="#curve">
        Dangerous Curves Ahead <tspan>uffa</tspan>
      </textPath>
    </text>
</svg>
```