# Is it possible to put a list in an <svg> tag in order to lay it on a curve?

Tags: html, css, svg, tags, curve

This is a follow up to [this question from earlier today](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67748676/5825294).

From the answer I accepted I understand that only [SVG elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element) are placed inside the SVG viewbox. However on the linked page I don't see a list-like thing listed.

So my question is: is it possible to put a `<ul>` inside `<textPath>`, so that I can lay the items along a curve?

Comment: you can't use a ul element however you can use several `<tspan>` elements instead

Answer (score 1):

SVG has no text layout functions like HTML has.  So the answer is **no**.

Unfortunately you have not told us what you mean by a "list".  Do you mean you want tyo havel several lines of text displayed one under another?

If you want to have parallel lines of text, then you have to lay it out manually yourself.

**Method 1**

In the example below we are using `<tspan>` elements to position individual lines of text.  The `<tspan>` element has a similar purpose to the HTML `<span>` element, but also allows some positioning.

Here we are using `x="0"` to reset the text position back to the start of the line. And the `dy="1em"` shifts the line down 1em from the last line of text.

```css
path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 500">

    <path id="curve" d="M73.2,148.6c4-6.1,65.5-96.8,178.6-95.6c111.3,1.2,170.8,90.3,175.1,97" />
    <text>
      <textPath xlink:href="#curve">
        Dangerous Curves Ahead
        <tspan x="0" dy="1em">Slippery When Wet</tspan>
        <tspan x="0" dy="1em">Danger Falling Rocks</tspan>
        <tspan x="0" dy="1em">Single Lane Bridge</tspan>
      </textPath>
    </text>
</svg>
```

You'll not that the text is getting more cramps on each line because the concave curve of the line is forcing the lower lines' character positions to get closer together.  If the curve was convex, the characters would be getting spaced further apart.

**Method 2**

If you don't want that effect, then you would need to put each line of text on its own path.

```css
path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 500">

    <path id="curve" d="M73.2,148.6c4-6.1,65.5-96.8,178.6-95.6c111.3,1.2,170.8,90.3,175.1,97" />
    <text>
      <textPath xlink:href="#curve">
        Dangerous Curves Ahead
      </textPath>
    </text>
    <text transform="translate(0, 16)">
      <textPath xlink:href="#curve">
        Slippery When Wet
      </textPath>
    </text>
    <text transform="translate(0, 32)">
      <textPath xlink:href="#curve">
        Danger Falling Rocks
      </textPath>
    </text>
    <text transform="translate(0, 48)">
      <textPath xlink:href="#curve">
        Single Lane Bridge
      </textPath>
    </text>
</svg>
```

**Update**

So akll you want is to put the text one after another?  The solution to that was so obvious that I didn't think that was what you meant.

Just do this:

```css
path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 500">

  <path id="curve" d="M73.2,148.6c4-6.1,65.5-96.8,178.6-95.6c111.3,1.2,170.8,90.3,175.1,97" />
  <text>
    <textPath xlink:href="#curve">
      Dangerous Curves Ahead
      Slippery When Wet
      Danger Falling Rocks
      Single Lane Bridge
    </textPath>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: I thought _so that I can lay the items along a curve_ was clearly indicating that I wanted items to be put on the curved line one after the other, but apparently I was wrong. Anyway, your first line answers the question, I believe. What I wanted to do is just not possible. I guess this is a lack of CSS.

Comment: @Enlico Just use a single text element with all the text in it then.